# ElasticSearch Aggregations in java spring boot 3 and spring Data Elasticsearch 5.x

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm trying to make an Elasticsearch query with Aggragation with Spring Data Elasticsearch 5.x.

Before updating elasticSearch and spring boot version i had the java code below that was working well :

```
    TermsQueryBuilder termsQueryBuilder1 = new TermsQueryBuilder("my_request","path1","path2");
    TermsQueryBuilder termsQueryBuilder2 = new TermsQueryBuilder("my_request","path2","path3");
    TermsQueryBuilder termsQueryBuilder3 = new TermsQueryBuilder("code","400","500");
    
    BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                    .filter(termsQueryBuilder2)
                    .filter(termsQueryBuilder3);
    
    TermsAggregationBuilder aggregationByDate = AggregationBuilders
        .terms("byDate")
        .script(new Script("doc['"@timestamp"'].value.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of('"America/Phoenix"')).toLocalDate()"))
        .order(BucketOrder.key(true))
        .size(30);
    
    
    TermsAggregationBuilder aggregationById = AggregationBuilders
        .terms("byId")
        .field(ID_FIELD)
        .order(BucketOrder.key(true))
        .subAggregation(aggregationByDate)
        .size(200);
    
    // Aggregation
    FiltersAggregationBuilder aggregation = AggregationBuilders
        .filters("attempts_by_date_and_id",
            new FiltersAggregator.KeyedFilter("success_try", termsQueryBuilder1),
            new FiltersAggregator.KeyedFilter("failed_try", boolQueryBuilder))
        .subAggregation(aggregationById);
```

how can i create a the terms and filters now that most of the classes are deprecated.